# Problems with Eclipse GUI

Tags: eclipse, jdk

Sometimes, without any evident pattern, Eclipse fails to render some stuff. I can't give much more information because the problem is difficult to reproduce, even if it appears often, and also even difficult to screenshot.

For example, when I maximize (or minimize) any view, it displays only the GUI elements of the old view and not them of the new one.

A simple typical scenario could be when I have an editor opened, I open a new editor and Eclipse display the text of the old editor instead of that of the new one; basically, it fails to display the updated gui.
This is a brief video explaining this scenario. Actually, when in the video I pause over a page editor, I double click on it (it isn't shown in the video, the screen recorder sucks), but as you can see nothing changes. In the end of the video, I drag the mouse as if I am selecting some text (again, the screen recorder doesn't show muose clicks) and the gui is updated
http://youtu.be/RFRotBqY9Fc

Here is also a more recent image of a broken gui
[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/2ls9xe1.png]
As you can see, there are a lot of cursors in various parts:  in package explorer, under "exit"; in "LoginView.java" in many points. Basically, I've only double clicked "LoginView.java" to show it in full screen.

Also, today I identified a specific sequence of events that always broke the GUIs, even if it is only a small part. When I am on a WindowsBuilder>Design view and I select refresh, this is the frame which contains the progress bar. As you can see, some elements were missing.

[image: http://i59.tinypic.com/11iliiw.png]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding to `eclipse.desktop`:

```
env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 SWT_GTK3=0
```

See [here](http://www.kaibader.de/fix-eclipse-luna-display-on-ubuntu-14-04/).